# input path does not exist apache-spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

Am new in spark but i have been trying to access a file and i keep on getting the same error no matter how much i tweak the code for locating the text file on my computer

```
lines = sc.textFile(r"Documents/python-spark-tutorial/in/word_count.txt").collect()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 816,
>   in collect
>       sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())   File
>   "C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 1257, in **call**   File
>   "C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line
>   63, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: ***An error
>   occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist:
>   file:/C:/Users/Home/Documents/python-spark-tutorial/in/word_count.txt***
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet.

```
sc.textFile("file:///path")
```

Comment: Thanks shiva i got the solution after realizing the extension on the file is text rather than txt that was my mistake its now solved

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved it was the file extension that i messed up with txt instead of text